# Displaying loading message - Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable

UPDATE:

here is how my html looks like and I have angularjs directive that created for datatables

```
<table id="vendor" ng-gridview="employee" resource="$employee">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-name="EmployeeId" data-width="50">Id</th>
      <th data-name="Name" data-width="75">Name</th>
      <th data-name="PhoneNumber" data-width="160">Phone Number</th>
      <th data-name="$options" data-width="160">Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

How would I display processing message in DataTables whenever it loads the records? I have 20K records and take around 10-15 seconds to load. I am using MVC 5 action method pass the data

I tried using `bProcessing` as true and `sProcessing` to give custom progress message but it does not work. How can I achieve that?

/*! DataTables 1.10.2 */

Here is my JQuery Datatables settings:

```
 settings = {
                        'data': scope[attrs.ngModel] || {},
                        'oLanguage': {
                            'sSearch': 'Search: _INPUT_',
                            'sLengthMenu': attrs.title || 'Display _MENU_ items.',
                            'sInfo': 'Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ items.',
                            "bProcessing": true,
                            "bServerSide": true,
                            "bDeferRender": true,

                            'sLoadingRecords': 'Please wait - loading...',
                            'sProcessing': '<div class="grid-loading"><img src="images/spinner.gif" width="32" align="middle" /> Loading</div>',
                            'sInfoEmpty': 'No entries to show'
                        },
                        'iDisplayLength': 10,
                        "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100],
                        'columnDefs': []
                    };
```

Comment: you should really consider to use some pagination anyway

Comment: yes I'm using pagination but still take that long

Comment: ah sorry, i was thinking you were displaying 20k records in table at once, my bad. And sorry, couldn't help you regarding your issue

Comment: your assumuption is correct its displaying 20k recoreds in table at once but i do have pagination and still take 10-15 seconds to load the page

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your table has `<table id="table">`

**HTML**

```
<div id="message">Loading, please wait</div>
<table id="table></table>
```

**CSS**

```
#table{
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#table').on('init.dt', function () {
    console.log('Table initialisation complete: ' + new Date().getTime());
    $('#table').show();
    $('#message').hide();
})
        .dataTable(settings);
```

Comment: I have updated my question and if you like to see my angularjs directive I can paste it

Comment: just change the js in my example to use id vendor the rest should be the same.

Comment: what happened instead

Comment: did you get chance to see?

Comment: @AbuHamzah I don't know Angular, so I don't think I would be much help there. Is your task to assign different keystrokes to different javascript functions, or is it something beyond that?

Answer (score 1):

[Duplicate] You can add in a spinner gif (find one here: http://www.ajaxload.info/) as a div where your table should be and then clear it when the table loads using initComplete.

Something like:

```
<img id="loading" src="/myspinner.gif">//put this right below `<div class="col-md-12">`
```

And then call your table like this:

```
var table = $('#tableId').DataTable( {

            initComplete: function(settings, json) {
                $("#tableId").removeClass("hide");
                $("#tableId").show();
                $("#loading").hide();
            },
     });
```

[Check it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970223/display-spinner-while-datatables-table-loads-ruby-on-rails)