# Display spinner while DataTables table loads Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

Using Rails I have built a web app. One of the pages of the web app displays a table which uses the [DataTables API](https://www.datatables.net/). This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcjpftyn/) shows an example of what my web app looks like.

The problem with this is that when I begin to add in large amounts of data (current test data is 1500 rows), the table loads each row first before running the javascript meaning you get an unformated table for a few seconds before the Javascript kicks in and DataTables activates.

I would like to display a spinner, or processing message (something along those lines) in place of the table until the page has fully populated, once that has finished I would like to run my javascript activating DataTables.

**EDIT: My main issue is I'm not sure how to use Javascript to display the spinner while the table loads but then change to the table once the page has finished loading**

My code is as follows:

#### HTML/eRB

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="app-list-table" class="display table" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table-headers">
                            <th>Header 1</th>
                            <th>Header 2</th>
                            <th>Header 3</th>
                            <th>Header 4</th>
                            <th>Header 5</th>
                            <th>Header 6</th>
                            <th>Header 7</th>
                            <th>Header 8</th>
                            <th>Header 9</th>
                            <th>Header 10</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <%= Server.find_each do |server| %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= link_to(server.server_name, server_path(server)) %></td>
                            <td><%= server.application %></td>
                            <td><%= server.server_role %></td>
                            <td><%= server.team_contact %></td>
                            <td><%= server.individual_contact %></td>
                            <td><%= server.business_owner %></td>
                            <td><%= server.vendor %></td>
                            <td><%= server.vendor_contact %></td>
                            <td><%= link_to("Click Here", server.main_doc) %></td>
                            <td><%= server.main_win %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <% end %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#app-list-table').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true

        });
    });
```

Please let me know if there is anything else you would like me to include.

Comment: [Spin.js](https://github.com/fgnass/spin.js/) is an option for the spinner itself. Everything else depends on what you want it to look like...

Comment: The spinner and it's design won't matter that much. My issue is I don't know where to add the js code to display the spinner while the page is loading and then display the table once it has loaded completely... Apologies I haven't made that clear enough in my question

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a bit of an amateur myself. But I don't think it's a DataTables issue... When my page loads it populated the entire HTML section before activating DataTables which leaves an unformatted table. I think DataTables is waiting on IT. Not the other way around

Comment: ETA: how is the data loaded? Is it asynchronous? To display the spinner on load, you want to load the spinner before the data, then remove it after its successfully loaded

Comment: The data is loaded as shown in the question. It uses embedded ruby to loop through each Object and populate the columns using the Object as a reference. I'm not sure if java script and ruby run asynchronously or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add in a spinner gif (find one here: http://www.ajaxload.info/) as a `div` where your table should be and then clear it when the table loads using `initComplete`.

Put something like this right below `<div class="col-md-12">`:

```
<img id="loadingSpinner" src="/myspinner.gif">
```

And then call your table like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#app-list-table').DataTable({
    //any other datatables settings here
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
      $('#loadingSpinner').hide();
      //or $('#loadingSpinner').empty();
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for hiding the spinner once the table loaded! Thank you. One more thing though is to have the table hidden from the time the page loads until DataTables has initialised. Is there a javascript function ti initialise code when the page has first loaded?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that as far as I know. If datatables can't find the div for the table, you'll get errors and it won't load. This includes if the div is hidden or added after the fact.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm going to try and hid the div some other way but your spinner implementation helped

Answer (score 1):

If the data is loaded in Ruby, there's no point in loading a spinner because the data has already loaded by then. This is a bare-bones ordering of what happens in your Rails app:

1. Controller then view Ruby executes, rendering HTML
2. HTML is sent to client
3. Client requests linked CSS and JS in order
4. CSS and JS execute in order
5. Asynchronous JS finishes

So, the majority of your delay is happening at step 1, but a CSS/JS spinner won't load until step 4. If you want to use a spinner, you need to load the data via async Ajax, so you can load the spinner in 4, then finish loading data and remove spinner in 5. Using jQuery Ajax:

```
var spinner = new Spinner().spin(document.getElementById('spinner'));
$.ajax("/your/data/path.json")
.done(function(data) {
  // load data here, then load table:
  var table = $('#app-list-table').DataTable({ … })
  // remove spinner
  $('#spinner').remove();
});
```

You could of course add the spinner to your current code:

```
var spinner = new Spinner().spin(document.getElementById('spinner'));
$('#app-list-table').DataTable({ 
  …
  initComplete: function() { $('#spinner').remove(); }
})
```

However, again, since most of the delay happens in Ruby, you'll only see the spinner for a brief moment at the end of the delay. To see the spinner for the whole delay, use Ajax.

Comment: Apologies I'm not looking to use AJAX. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to hide the datatable until it's ready, it is possible to do this by putting the datatable inside a div that is initially set to display:none and then showing the div after you've initialised the datatable... I also included an opaque overlay div over the whole page while the datatable(s) are loading and a delay of 500 ms to force the loading effect.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {

 $(function(){
    function loadDataTable(){
  
   var dataTableId = $('#dataTableId').dataTable({"initComplete": function(settings, json) {$('.overlay').hide();});
   $('#divContatingDataTable').show();
 };
    window.setTimeout(loadDataTable, 500);
 });

});
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
 .overlay {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
 }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
 This div / overlay contains a loading message / image and can be styled however you like
 <img class="loading" src="loading.gif" />
</div>


<div id="divContatingDataTable" style="display:none;">
 <!-- Datatable contents with id dataTableId go here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive used the code provided on the link below, but insteat of using an old jquery version you should use the latest one (3.x), otherwise Datatables will crash. Hope this help

http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/