# How to show a loading message till data loads in jquery Data tables

Tags: reactjs, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables in react. I fetch data and then pass it as props to jQuery datatables. Want to show a loading icon/ message till datatable receives the data.

The option `processing: true` doesn't work for me.

Following is the initialisation:

```
$('.table').DataTable({ 
   retrieve: true
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i display loading/processing message inside DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650954/how-can-i-display-loading-processing-message-inside-datatable)

Comment: you can use initComplete API function and inside that you can toggle showing loading icon/image like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970223/display-spinner-while-datatables-table-loads-ruby-on-rails

Comment: The initComplete worked. Thanks.